# How to include an article's full text in a PHP based RSS feed?

Tags: php, rss, feed

My feed.php page pulls content from the mySQL database to generate the feed.  For years I only had a single sentence that I put into the description field.  Now I would like to instead include the full text.  But the RSS 2.0 spec doesn't have a field designated for an article's full text.  Do I just put the full text into the description or is there a more logical option?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - yes. you put the full article text inside the description
Most rss readers will show the text to a certain extent, based on their styling, and will show the full article text once focused

there are other xml rss matching standards, that can be "embedded" in the xml (that can support all formats in parallel)
a few:

```
  xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
  xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"
  xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
  xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
  xmlns:admin="http://webns.net/mvcb/"
  xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
```

feedly, maybe the most popular reader out there, supports another format, which is more robust:

```
xmlns:webfeeds="http://webfeeds.org/rss/1.0
```